# How to pass parameters with spaces via cstdlib system

Tags: c++, std

I have this windows console app which takes a file, do some calculations, and then writes the output to a specified file. The input is specified in "app.exe -input fullfilename" format. I need to call this application from my C++ program, but I have a problem with spaces in paths to files. When I call the app directly from cmd.exe by typing (without specifying output file for clarity)

```
"c:\first path\app.exe" -input "c:\second path\input.file"
```

everything works as expected. But, when I try using cstdlib std::system() function, i.e.

```
std::system(" \"c:\\first path\\app.exe\" -input \"c:\\second path\\input.file\" ");
```

the console prints out that c:\first is not any valid command. It's probably common mistake and has simple solution, but I have been unable to find any. Thx for any help.

Comment: Have you tried escaping the spaces too?

Comment: In UNIX systems, this is the responsibility of the shell, and it should work. I'm not sure who has that responsibility on Windows, but I bet it makes a difference whether you're using MSVC++ or MinGW or Cygwin. Could you tell us what compiler you're using?

Comment: This seems to work, not sure why though:`std::system(" \"\"c:\\first path\\app.exe\" -input \"c:\\second path\\input.file\"\" ");`

Comment: Troubadour:
It does exactly the same.
Ken Bloom:
MS VS 2008 Prof. Ed.
Naveen:
Yes, this really seems to work, thank you! But I am unsure about it as well..

Comment: Naveen: After few minutes of testing a different problem showed up. Although your code does work, cmd.exe now complains about length of the command. It seems that the "command name" portion of the cmd must not be longer than 259 characters, although with parameters it is allowed to use up to 8190 characters. The outer quotes caused that command line is processed as a single command without parameters and due to specifying full paths to files the command length now easily exceeds allowed max. of 259 chars..

Answer (score 1):

Instead of std::system(), you should use the _wspawnv function from the Windows API. Use _wspawnvp if you want to search for the program in PATH, rather than specifying a full path to it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <wchar.h>
...
const WCHAR *app = L"C:\\path to\\first app.exe";
const WCHAR *argv[] = {app, L"-input", L"c:\\second path\\input file.txt"};
_wpspawnv(_P_WAIT, app, argv);
```

You could also use _spawnv / _spawnvp if you are 100% sure that your input filename will never, ever contain anything else than ASCII.

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to put the quotes in the std::system() call.  Try the following:

```
std::system("c:\\first\\ path\\app.exe -input c:\\second\\ path\\input.file");
```